# React Native: How to securely store API client secrets?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

If I'm creating an IOS React Native app, where is the best place to store client secrets for external APIs? I see a lot of tutorials and such that just hard code them, but proceed to say something along the lines of *"DON'T DO THIS"* without actually providing a valid example of how to actually do it for something production level.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to store API keys or any private data in the code of your app. Apps aswell as websites can be read by others. Better store your key on a server and access it with http requests

Comment: So if I used something like Firebase, I would still need to key to that, right? At some point, it seems like the client has to store some key/secret.

Comment: You're right but the firebase key for example can be limited to specific domains or app ids so only you can use it on your app/website

Comment: Got it. So basically I could just store my client secrets in Firebase, store my Firebase key in the react client, and retrieve the secrets from Firebase when I need them? Since the key for Firebase is locked to my app specifically, it would be okay to just have that hard coded or set in some config?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that a "hacker" _could_ manually get your api key for example by creating a new function in your app code which retrieves your api key from firebase with the same request you did. I know this is very theoretically but possible. A really safe solution is to work for example with Firebase Cloud Functions and the Firebase Admin SDK. You can store your api key in the database but also directly in cloud functions because it's on a server. Now you can create a function with your api methods and request it with a http request.

Comment: Thats a similar approach I've taken with a ASP.NET Core app that has a React front end. Essentially using Core for "proxy" APIs that store secrets, tokens, etc., and route the calls to the actual external APIs. I was hoping there would be an easier solution, but it seems like this type of approach is safer for now.

Comment: Still not a real answer.For instance my react native app makes request to my web api  by using bearer authentication.How can I prevent my secrets to be revealed by reverse engineering or decompiling ?